# Selecting subset of columns in table based on their names using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, nested-select

I have a table in Postgres DB which has a lot of columns such as "id, name, a01, a02, a03, ..., a20, b, c, d, e, f". I want to check whether any of these 'aXX' columns has value 'Y'.
I know the trivial way which is:

```
SELECT name FROM table T 
WHERE T.a01 = Y OR T.a02 = Y OR ... OR T.a20 = Y
```

I was wondering if there is any way to use a loop or nested select query based on these column names since they have a pattern, instead of hard-coding them individually in WHERE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may use dynamic SQL to build your query ...

Comment: This is one of many reasons why database normalization is important

Comment: @RadimBača Do you know how? I could not figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Imposible in SQL but...

## You can do it in PostgreSQL

If you only want the id, the field name (key) and the value you can write:

```
select d.id, e.key, e.value
  from the_data d, jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(d.*)) e
  where value::integer = -1;
```

If you want the row you can:

```
select * 
  from the_data
  where id in (
    select d.id
      from the_data d, jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(d.*))
      where value::integer = -1
  );
```

See the running example in: http://rextester.com/CRGXPS45970

## EDITED

You can filter fields or what you want. For example:

```
select d.id, e.key, e.value
  from the_data d, jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(d.*)) e
  where value::integer = -1 and key like 'a%';

select * 
  from the_data
  where id in (
    select d.id
      from the_data d, jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(d.*))
      where value::integer = -1 and key like 'a%'
  );
```

You can see it here: http://rextester.com/EESKX21438

Comment: Thanks you very much! It is very close to the answer I am looking, I want only search in columns which starts with 'a'. ( In your example 'a1', 'a2', 'a3' and 'a10'). I have all 'a1' to 'a20' in my table. Is it possible to filter columns names like that, when we are converting to json?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do exactly what you want to do. You could do another query first to fetch all the column names, then process your result in PHP, but I think that is even more complex than just writing columns' names down.